# "Close unrelated projects" function gone in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, project, maven-plugin, galileo

I can't find the once existing and oh so handy "Close unrelated projects" function in my Eclipse IDE any more.

Are there any conditions for this dialog option to appear? I've got the Eclipse Maven plugin installed, could this have any effects the option?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that it's a newer feature than your current installation? It's certainly present in my Helios installation (build 20100204-0846) - right click on an open project and "Close unrelated projects" is an option just below "Close project".

Comment: No, it's definitely in Galileo too.

Answer (score 0):

> I've got the Eclipse Maven plugin installed, could this have any effects the option?

Shouldn't do.  I'm running Helios SR 1 with the Maven plugin, and the option is in the menu.

It could be something silly like Eclipse needing a restart.

Or maybe you didn't have a project selected when you right-clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I had the same problem today.
My problem was that I had opened up the C/C++ Projects View which does NOT have the "Close unrelated projects" option.  The Navigator View  does have that option.   The two views are so similar that I didn't realize what I had done.  Perhaps others have done the same.

Answer (score 0):

That option is sometimes missing from context menus in the Package Explorer in Eclipse 3.7.x.  It's there one day and gone the next, with no apparent changes to anything.  I've never been able to figure out what the conditions are for its appearance or lack thereof.  But when it's gone, it's sorely missed.

Comment: Its presence or absence is still seemingly random in Eclipse Luna.